# opencv3 videoCapture (windows) doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, opencv, opencv3.0

I've a problem with openCV 3 java wrapper.

When i use videocapture, camera.grab() always return false.
I see several subjects on internet about this problem. I succeeded to run opencv 2.4 but not with version 3.

My environnement :

- windows 10 (64b)
- java 8u51 (32b)
- eclipse mars (32b)

So, I test these methods.
Env :

- Set windows path : D:\Programs\opencv3x\build\x86\vc12\bin
- Add opencv_ffmpeg to  D:\Programs\opencv3x\build\x86\vc12\bin (in opencv 3, this lib is already in with the good name :  opencv_ffmpeg300.dll).

Dev env :
In eclipse project :

- add opencv-300.jar
- set the native lib to D:/Programs/opencv3x/build/java/x86

With this configuration, I can use opencv 3 without problem...but i can't decode video file!

Does anyone have a solution on this? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LFtICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41

> It might also be the case where the opencv_ffmpeg300 dynamic link
>   library goes missing from your path environmental variable. Try
>   copying it to your project home folder

Copy opencv_ffmpeg300.dll direct to your Eclipse project's home folder ("or add it to your path variable").